# How can I change the class of TD table. After the page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay I have an HTML page.
Inside this page I have a table with rows and columns.
For each TD element.
I have an "idnum" attribute.
Now I also have one ARRAY.
In this ARRAY I have 3 objects. More accurate 3 numbers.
With a good look, look at the numbers that match the numbers in the table.
Now I want each object in the table whose number is in ARRAY.
Will get a straight red background color.
More accurate that the object of another class.
Who has an idea how can I solve this?
Thank you all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.numeric.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        td:hover{
            color: red;
        }
        .class1{

        }
        .class2{
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <td class="class1" idnum="111">TD1</td>
        <td class="class1" idnum="222">TD2</td>
        <td class="class1" idnum="333">TD3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h1 id="content"></h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     var array1 = ["111","222","333"];
     for(var i = 0; i<array1.length; i++){
        $("#content").append(i+"-->"+array1[i] + "</br>" );
        var count = array1[i];
         var td = $("*").find("td").attr("idnum");
            if(td == array1[i]){
                $(this).toggleClass("class2");
            }

     }
});


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".class1").on("click", function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("class2");
        var idnum = $(this).attr("idnum");
            alert("idnum is " + idnum);
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.numeric.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        td:hover{
            color: red;
        }
        .class1{

        }
        .class2{
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <td class="class1" idnum="111">TD1</td>
        <td class="class1" idnum="444">TD2</td>
        <td class="class1" idnum="333">TD3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h1 id="content"></h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     var array1 = ["111","444","333"];


        $("td").each(function(){
            var td = ($(this).attr("idnum"));
            for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
           if(td == array1[i])
            $(this).addClass("class2");
            }

        })
    })




    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".class1").on("click", function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("class2");
        var idnum = $(this).attr("idnum");
            alert("idnum is " + idnum);
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, I solved.
I just used the function () each and it works like I wanted to thank everyone.